# Thymeleaf: Facebook Share URL

Tags: spring, facebook, thymeleaf

This static link is shareable on facebook:

```html
<td><div class="w3-text-white w3-btn w3-indigo w3-hover-blue w3-tiny w3-border"
data-href="https://www.i-koda.com/delivery/dsr?uft=347822&amp;c=348702     
https://www.i-koda.com/delivery/dsr?uft=347822&amp;c=348702 
https://www.i-koda.com/delivery/dsr?uft=347822&amp;c=$48702
https://www.i-koda.com/delivery/dsr?uft=347822&amp;c=348702" 
data- layout="button_count" 
data-size="small" 
data-mobile-iframe="true">
<a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" style="color:white" 
href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.i-koda.com%2Fdelivery%2Fdsr%3Fuft%3D347822%26c%3D348702&amp;src=sdkpreparse">
Share the Results</a></div></td>
```

However, I need to insert dynamic values for the get parameters (e.g., ...|uft=${user.uft}|...   ). I am using Thymeleaf and Spring.

th:data-href does not seem to be a Thymeleaf attribute. Can someone tell me how to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use th:attr

```html
<div class="w3-text-white w3-btn w3-indigo w3-hover-blue w3-tiny w3-border" th:attr="data-href=|https://www.i-koda.com/delivery/dsr?uft=${vwUser.getActiveTest().getUserFullTestId()}&amp;c=${vwUser.id} https://www.i-koda.com/delivery/dsr?uft=${vwUser.getActiveTest().getUserFullTestId()}&amp;c=${vwUser.id} https://www.i-koda.com/delivery/dsr?uft=${vwUser.getActiveTest().getUserFullTestId()}&amp;c=${vwUser.id} https://www.i-koda.com/delivery/dsr?uft=${vwUser.getActiveTest().getUserFullTestId()}&amp;c=${vwUser.id}  |" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" style="color:white" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.i-koda.com%2Fdelivery%2Fdsr%3Fuft%3D347822%26c%3D348702&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share the Results</a></div>
```